# Is there an API call that lists all currently running airflow jobs?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I would like to know if there is a simple API call I can make to list all currently running airflow jobs.

In the airflow flower dashboard, there is a column that lists all currently active jobs. I'd like to know if I can obtain this information via an API call.

Comment: Try to take hint from [`Airflow`-**CLI**](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/bin/cli.py); here [`list_tasks(..)`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/bin/cli.py#L623) and [`list_dags(..)`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/bin/cli.py#L608) methods might be of interest

Comment: One of the way is : Go to Apache-Airflow UI ->Data Profiling->Ad Hoc Query -> select airflow_db and query this "select * from task_instance where state="running/success/failed"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: no. Airflow does have an experimental REST API, but there is no endpoint for the call you're after. See https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/98e852219fc73c7ec049feeab7305bc7c0e89698/airflow/api/client/json_client.py#L26 for a list of the endpoints supported (Some of them are mentioned in the official documentation as well: https://airflow.apache.org/api.html#endpoints)

As far as I understand a proper non-experimental REST API is on the roadmap of Airflow 2.

Answer (score 0):

If your REST API is enabled you can do the following,

your URL should look like this:

```
https://<your-airflow-uri>/home
```

you can use the following in order to get the list of running tasks

```
https://<your-airflow-uri>/api/v1/dags/~/dagRuns/~/taskInstances?state=running
```

it should look like this

- for the example I used the state **queued**
  [image]