# How to get list of the tasks running within airflow dag

Tags: airflow

How can I get the list of tasks running within an airflow dag having the dag-id? The connection between tasks doesn't matter. Thanks

Say I have the dag-id from "airflow list_dags"

Comment: You need the list of tasks inside an airflow DAG? The task_instance table in airflow stores this information. Depending on the config `core__sqlalchemy_conn` the answer might vary.

Comment: You have the option to get it using REST API as well. [Running tasks in airflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54297299/is-there-an-api-call-that-lists-all-currently-running-airflow-jobs/76978015#76978015)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get the list of tasks inside of a DAG, you could use:

```
from airflow import settings
from airflow.models import TaskInstance
from airflow.utils.state import State
import logging


def print_running_tasks():
    session = settings.Session()
    for task in session.query(TaskInstance) \
            .filter(TaskInstance.state == State.RUNNING) \
            .all():
        logging.info(f'task_id: {task.task_id}, dag_id: {task.dag_id}, start_date: {task.start_date}, '
                     f'hostname: {task.hostname}, unixname: {task.unixname}, job_id: {task.job_id}, pid: {task.pid}')
```

This snippet print the information of the running tasks. You could remove the `.filter()` in order to get all the tasks regardless their status.

Answer (score 0):

I think `$ airflow list_tasks [DAG-ID]` is what you're looking for.

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/1.10.9/cli.html#list_tasks

Comment: It's there a way to perform the same but within a DAG?

Comment: What do you mean by "within the DAG"?
The DAG is a python object. One of the properties are the tasks.
I imagine something like `your_dag.tasks` gives you the list of tasks/operators

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_modules/airflow/models/dag.html#DAG.tasks
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/models/dag/index.html#airflow.models.dag.DAG.tasks

Comment: I mean: Create a DAG that could get the list of all tasks, ie: get the list of tasks using python (that's what i mean with: within the DAG). Something like I posted below